# Issue: Violation of Permissions policy After reviewing your app while uploading Android app on Store

Tags: android, google-play, sms, privacy-policy

While uploading my Android app , I receive a rejected mail from Google says that

> Issue: Violation of Permissions policy After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):
>   Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality { Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls, SMS-based financial transactions (e.g., 5 digit messages), and related activity including OTP account verification for financial transactions and fraud detection, Track, budget, manage SMS-based financial transactions (e.g., 5 digit messages) and related account verification }. Please remove these permissions from your app.
>   Your app seems to be a {Violation Monitoring app} and does not meet any of the allowed use cases. Hence, we cannot provide SMS/Call Log permissions.

I tried to search on it and I didn't find a real solution for my problem

Here is my Permissions

````
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
     />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
    />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
     />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" /> ```
````

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: anyway ... mail is pretty clear: remove RECEIVE_SMS and READ_SMS permissions

Comment: Maybe someone has faced this problem before and then I can get help

Comment: When I remove it , SMS function will still working ? @Selvin

Comment: I use the permissions of SMS to detect the number in the message without copy it for example and write it in my application . so If i deleted this permission , My Function won't work . @Selvin

Comment: @AhmedElsayed what purpose are you using read sms permission in your app

Answer (score 0):

My app used read sms permission which allowed my app read otp sms send to user mobile device to verify user mobile number. 
So i too received this violation policy permission mail stating i am using read sms permission in my app.
Using that permission i was able toread OTP automatically from the sms.
But according to new google guidelines,we cant use read sms permission for above mentioned account verification.
So right now i have removed sms read permission and made user to enter the otp received in sms manually.

If you are using read sms permission ,there are certain requirements to be met.

> **For apps requesting access to the SMS or Call Log permissions, the intended and permitted uses include default SMS handling, default
>   phone handling, or Assistant handling capability.
>  Apps must be
>   actively registered as the default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler
>   before prompting users to accept any of the above permissions and must
>   immediately stop the use of the permission when they no longer are the
>   default handler.**

I got information from this link.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303
Hope this helps you.